# Change template via parameter when render a controller action?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I got a simple CRUD-controller with a indexAction() to list all items. Now I want render this action within another template and change the .

```
{{ render(controller("MyBundle:MyEntity:index")) }}
```

Is there a predefined parameter to change the template? Sure its easy to pass this value, but I don't want reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Rendering a controller, delegates all stuff to the controller action. The action decides which template to render.

Comment: Sure and I want to tell the controller use another template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native parameter to change the template but you can pass an argument to the action defined by the `render` method ...

```
{ render(controller('MyBundle:MyEntity:index', { 'template': 'MyBundle:ControllerName:foo.html.twig' })) }}
```

... and use it inside your controller action to decide which template to render.

```
class MyEntityController
{
     public function indexAction($template = null)
     {
         // ... some code here

         $template = $template ? $template : 'MyBundle:ControllerName:index.html.twig';

         return $this->render(
             $template,
             array(
               'variable' => $variable,
             )
         );
     }
```

Comment: Thank you, thats all I wanted to know.