# Symfony2.7 : Twig render controller() ignore my parameters

Tags: symfony, templates, controller, twig, twig-extension

I have a trouble with a symfony exeption and some parameter i try to get. I have absolutely no idea why i get this exception after thousands checks of my code and on the internet.

The exception is :

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Some mandatory parameters are missing ("slug") to generate a URL for route "blogcomment_create".") in @Blog\Default\Blog\singlePost.html.twig at line 29.

The route configuration :

```
blogcomment_create:
    path:   /{slug}/comment/create/
    defaults: { _controller: "BlogBundle:Comment:create" }
    requirements: { methods: post }
```

My code in my twig template to import my controller:

```
<footer>
    {{ render(controller('BlogBundle:Comment:create', {
        'slug': Post.slugname
    })) }}
</footer>
```

My Action declaration :

```
 public function createAction(Request $request, $slug = null)
{
    //...
}
```

I starting to get mad with this exception, i have no clues why i get her and i realy need a good pair of eyes.

i try tons of exemples :

[How to insert a Controller in Twig with "render" in Symfony 2.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221230/how-to-insert-a-controller-in-twig-with-render-in-symfony-2-2)

[symfony2 - twig - how to render a twig template from inside a twig template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717438/symfony2-twig-how-to-render-a-twig-template-from-inside-a-twig-template)

[Change template via parameter when render a controller action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678339/change-template-via-parameter-when-render-a-controller-action)

...

Here a dump of the fonction :

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerReference)[992]
    public 'controller' => 
        string 'BlogBundle:Comment:create' (length=31)
    public 'attributes' => 
        array (size=1)
            'slug' => string 'article-de-test-yolowowo' (length=24)
    public 'query' => 
        array (size=0)
            empty
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i finaly get it !

The problem was not at all in my twig template but in my controller. I have a fonction to generate my form in this controller. I call her in my action :

```
private function createCreateForm(Comment $entity, $slug)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new CommentType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('blogcomment_create', array('slug' => $slug)),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

    return $form;
}
```

In this function i forgot to pass parameters in this fonction :

```
$this->generateUrl()
```

I really need to sleep sooner when i get that kind of problems >.>

I hope my problem will help other peoples in the future.